# Can I make other Sims break up?

Tags: the-sims-3

If I know a Sim who has a partner, but I want my Sim to be that Sim's partner, can I make them break up? For example, if I romance it hard enough, will an option like "ask to break up with partner" or similar become available? Or is it impossible?

Comment: I trust you're not planning on doing this in real life anytime soon - or pretty much ever.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro No I am not planning that :) I am just trying to have a kid with all ladies in sunset valley, because I am bored after getting "heartbreaker" wish.

Comment: @yasar11732 You can have a kid with her without making her break up too, I think :P

Comment: @Kareen If I go steady, They will show up as ex-girlfriend in relationships panel, that helps me count :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make other Sims break up. If you perform enough romantic actions with the Sim you are interested in, you will have the option of asking that Sim to break up with his or her partner, assuming the Sim in question is now a "Romantic Interest", as opposed to "Friend", "Good Friend" or "Best Friend". You will then be able to ask them to go steady, propose to them and eventually marry them.

Keep in mind that by asking a Sim to break up with their partner, you automatically make yourself an enemy of that now ex-partner.

Comment: Not a TS3 player - is "romance" really a verb in-game? Maybe in Simlish it is...

Comment: It's not really, no. The way things work, you click on a Sim, a pie of options such as Friendly, Funny, Mean, Romantic pop up, and you choose action in sub pies of options. I could perhaps make it clearer in my answer.

Comment: Ah, I was just wondering. I was editing the question, and couldn't figure out for the life of me how to change that particular phrase as it sounded quite... wrong.

Comment: I'd say you could go for "perform enough romantic actions" or something along those lines.

Comment: @Kareen I am trying this right now :)

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro [Yes, romance can be used as a verb.](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+romance) `Romance (v.) - 1. court; woo ("the wealthy estate owner romanced her") 2. another term for romanticize ("to a certain degree I am romancing the past")`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can. All you have to do is perform enough love actions with the sim you like and then the sim you would like to break up with will become a friend. (enemy, I guess.)

Comment: This does not really add anything that was not more thoroughly explained in the nearly 3 year old answer.

Answer (score 0):

YES. The old-fashioned way is to simply engage in romantic interactions while their partner watches or wait until a rumor hits about it.

If you have the University expansion, the Social Networking skill eventually unlocks the ability to freely alter social status between sims using your smart-phone app.

Supernatural can also break relations ships via love curses or certain potions similar to the old fashioned method by making sims fall in love with someone else which will eventually break the relationship.

If you have show-time, a genie can control a sim, temporary granting you the ability to use them as you see fit, and can simply call and break up with their partner, sell their house, vehicles, insult their children and friends, quit their job, and otherwise ruin their life.